# Python list that should be empty when appending empty lists

Tags: python, list

I wrote a small Python script below that is behaving in a way I did not anticipate, but I cannot pinpoint the error. Specifically, I have a variable `xyz_all` that I'd expect to be empty because I'm only ever appending an empty list to it, but in reality it contains the elements of `xyz`. How is this possible?

```
with open(filename,'r') as rf:
    xyz = []
    xyz_all = []
    for line in rf:
        if 'A' in line:
            line = line.split()
            xyz.append([float(j) for j in line[4:7]])
        elif 'B' in line:
            xyz = []
            xyz_all.append(xyz)
print(xyz_all)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ever append empty lists to `xyz_all`, but those lists don't stay empty. When you do

```
xyz.append([float(j) for j in line[4:7]])
```

you're appending to a list that may already be an element of `xyz_all`.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I totally missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From your code,
xyz will be an empty list of length zero but when you do
     xyz = []
     xyz_all.append(xyz)
you are appending an empty list (xyz) to list (xyz_all) which means now xyz_all has one element in it which is an empty list and its length is not zero but 1.
xyz_all=[[]] is a list containing an empty list in it.

Comment: In the elif loop you reinitialized xyz to an empty list then how can xyz not be empty?

Comment: This is not correct. `xyz_all` contains numerical values at the end of the script.